# Does SWT Canvas Provide Tools For Mouse Move/Click Active Areas?

Tags: java, canvas, mouse, swt

I'm creating an application with Java and SWT, and have a workspace generated on a Canvas.  I need to make certain areas (controls) on the canvas trigger an event when mouseover-ed or clicked.  Of course this could be done by listening to the MouseMoveEvent and checking the location of the mouse manually, but I would like to know if SWT provides an easier way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, Paul.  I finally created an ArrayList of Rectangle objects for each control.  Whenever the mousemove event triggers, I loop through each Rectangle and call Rectangle.contains() with the mouse coordinates.  This solution turned out to be very organized.

In my case, the control events are homogenous (they all do the same thing), but if anyone has multiple control actions, Rectangle.data can be used to contain a Command object.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no facility to automate this. You will need to register mouse listeners and investigate the `x` & `y` coordinates manually.

A different approach might be adding individual `Canvas` objects onto an enclosing `Canvas`. This way, you could add listeners to the individual controls. This will, however, use more memory (as the underlying object has a buffer, as well as the control on top) and redrawing will be more CPU intensive.

My personal preference goes to the first technique.